# What would be the complexity of this algorithm implementation of 0 1 knapsack?

Tags: c, knapsack-problem

In the recursive version of the code I used a look up table to avoid re computation. But I couldn't figure out if it is better than the bottom up approach.So is it better? and I have tried solving with n = 20 and it didn't give a stack overflow error. So, is this approach fine? And also if I try to use W = 90 in the same code with all other inputs kept same(as in the code below), I get some garbage value as the answer, why?
I understand that declaring *look* array globally with maximum values isn't good approach(wastage of memory). I could instead declare it in main function dynamically of size n x W+1 and I tried. But when I tried to pass it in the function it(Dev-C++) gave me a warning, passing arg from incompatible pointer type and ignoring the warning at first and running the program I got nothing in the output.What possibly might be the reason.
PS: I am a beginner and thanks a lot in advance.

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #define MAXN 20
  #define MAXW 100

  int look[MAXN][MAXW];

  int max(int a, int b){
         return (a > b)? a : b; 
  }


 int knapSack(int W, int wt[], int val[], int n){

      if (n == -1 || W == 0)
          return 0;
      if(look[n][W]!=-1)
          return look[n][W];

      if (wt[n] > W){
          look[n-1][W]=knapSack(W, wt, val, n-1);
          look[n][W]=look[n-1][W];
      }

      else   
           look[n][W]=max( val[n] + knapSack(W-wt[n], wt, val, n-1),knapSack(W, wt, val, n-1));

      return look[n][W];
  }

  int main(){

      int val[] = {7,4,5,1};
      int wt[] = {5,4,3,1};
      int i,j,W = 7;
      int n = sizeof(val)/sizeof(val[0]);

      for(i=0;i<n;i++)
          for(j=0;j<=W;j++)look[i][j]=-1; 
              printf("%d", knapSack(W, wt, val, n-1));
      return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I get some garbage value as the answer, why?

Look at the initial statements in function `knapSack()`:

```
      if(look[n][W]!=-1)
          return look[n][W];
      if (n == -1 || W == 0)
          return 0;
```

The function can through recursion be called with `n` being -1, for which you cater in the second `if` statement, but that's too late, since in the first `if` condition you already access the undefined value `look[-1][W]`. You may want to reverse the order of those two statements.

Comment: Thanks, that was a big mistake I did there. But assuming this mistake is corrected what would be the complexity ?

Comment: The worst-case time complexity is O(n²).